# Get QR code from input texts

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I have a website where I request for information and now I want to generate a QR code where i have access of what I have written in those values. This is my code of the labels

```
 <form action="action_page.php">
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="Value1"> // transform this and the below in only one QR code
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="Value2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: and where is the php/qr code for all this?

Comment: Thats the code I want :)

Comment: The question is too broad then, meaning that there stands to be too many possible answers where some stand to be wrong (and may get downvoted for it). Try something out and when you have trouble with something, we'll be more than happy to help ;-)